# How do you determine which validator condition failed in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-validation, angular-validator

for example I have an input , and I add muti validate conditions like:
required , mail and pattern , so any one failed will lead the controls.status gave me "INVALID" , what shall I do if I want to know which one is failed?

Comment: are you using template driven forms or reactive forms?

Comment: write in .html {{control?.errors|json}} and you  will see the errors

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To display errors when using template driven forms:

```
<input type="text" 
       id="name"
       required
       [(ngModel)]="model.name" 
       name="name"
       #name="ngModel">
<div>{{name.errors | json}}</div>
```

To display errors when using reactive forms:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>
  <div>{{profileForm.get('firstName').errors | json}}</div>
</form>
```

I suggest to use or create some directive/component which will display errors for you.

Answer (score 7):

if you use reactive forms ,  **hasError** Function to check validators type , this is a example:

```
<input matInput placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" [formControl]="firstName" name="fname" required>

<mat-error *ngIf="firstName.hasError('required')">
    First Name is required.
</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="firstName.hasError('minlength')">
    First Name is too short.
</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="firstName.hasError('maxlength')">
    First Name is too long.
</mat-error>
```